# Get the filename of applicationCache progress event

Tags: javascript, html, caching, manifest

The Chrome Developer tool displays on the console the name of the file being downloaded from the manifest.
This occurs when the event `window.applicationCache.onprogress` fires.
Is there away to get the filename that is been dwld with javascript?
e.g. I would like something like this `e.filename`

```
window.applicationCache.onprogress=function(e) {
   if(e.lengthComputable){
      document.getElementById('progressBar').value=Math.round(e.loaded/e.total*100);
   }
   sideNotice=document.getElementById('sideNotice');
   sideNotice.innerHTML+="Downloading "+e.filename+"<br/>";
};
```

Comment: I cannot find either, and response to this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121130/html-offline-application-cache-listing-downloaded-files) suggest that it's not possible yet.